# Select query with Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to select the table values with (`group by`) options. `Table1`  contains the list of week data I need to sum and group the values based on the `Desc 2`,

**Table1:**

```
╔════════╦═══════╦════════╦═══════╗
║     ID ║ Desc  ║ Desc 2 ║  Amt  ║
╠════════╬═══════╬════════╬═══════╣
║      1 ║ Total ║ Spent  ║ 25.00 ║
║      2 ║ Total ║ Net    ║ 55.00 ║
║      3 ║ Total ║ Spent  ║ 78.00 ║
║      4 ║ Total ║ avg    ║ 99.00 ║
║      5 ║ Total ║ Net    ║ 54.00 ║
║      6 ║ Total ║  vv    ║ 58.00 ║
║      7 ║ Total ║  vv    ║ 55.00 ║ 
║      8 ║ Total ║ avg    ║ 55.00 ║ 
╚════════╩═══════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

I need a select query as below from the `Table1`

**Result Table:**

```
╔════════╦═══════╦════════╦═══════╗
║     ID ║ Desc  ║ Desc 2 ║  Amt  ║
╠════════╬═══════╬════════╬═══════╣
║      1 ║ Total ║ Null   ║479.00 ║
║      2 ║ Total ║ Net    ║109.00 ║
║      3 ║ Total ║ Spent  ║103.00 ║
║      4 ║ Total ║ avg    ║154.00 ║
║      5 ║ Total ║ vv     ║113.00 ║
╚════════╩═══════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: Try my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an extra row for grand total amount, you can use [`GROUPING SETS`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE 
(
    ID int IDENTITY (1,1),
    [Desc] varchar(10),
    Desc2 varchar(10),
    Amt int
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
(
    [Desc],
    Desc2,
    Amt
)
VALUES
('Total','Spent',25), 
('Total','Net',55), 
('Total','Spent',78), 
('Total','avg',99), 
('Total','Net',54), 
('Total','vv',58), 
('Total','vv',55), 
('Total','avg',55)

SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY [desc],[desc2]) AS Id,
      [Desc], Desc2, sum(Amt) AS SumAmt
FROM @SampleData sd
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (([Desc], Desc2), ([Desc]))
```

See my demo here http://rextester.com/OYTFG21446

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
select desc , desc2 ,sum(amt) as T_amt from table1 group by desc ,dec2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Desc)ID,* 
FROM(
    SELECT Desc, Desc2,SUM(Amt)Amt 
    FROM Your_Table
    GROUP BY Desc, Desc2
    )D
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT ID, Desc, Desc2, SUM(Amt) as amount
FROM table1
GROUP BY Desc2
```

NOTE:
if "Desc" is your real field name, change it to something else, because SQL parser will confuse it with "DESC" in ORDER BY clause.

Comment: This will not give the expected result, because ID is included.